# Android File.mkdirs() returns false while trying to create a directory in sdcard

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

I know this is a many times asked question in Stackoverflow and I have seen those questions. The answers suggested checking the permission, restarting device, check if the parent directory exists etc. I tried all of them and its still not working.

I have `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission specified in manifest.

The following is my code.

```
        File newFile = new File(parent.getCanonicalPath() + "/" + dirName + "/");
        if(!newFile.exists()){
            boolean created = newFile.mkdirs();
            if(!created){
                int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                boolean permissionGranted = (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create directory " 
                        + ", Parent exists : " + parent.exists()
                        + ", Parent Dir writable : " + parent.canWrite()
                        + ", Permission granted : " + permissionGranted);

            }
        }
```

And the log prints

`Could not create directory, Parent exists : true, Parent Dir writable : true, Permission granted : true`

I have gained write permission to sdcard through its TreeUri and then I converted the tree uri to actual path to use it with the File class.

My minSdkVersion is 19 and targerSdkVersion is 25

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit :

I tried all of the above suggestions but failed. Now, I fixed the issue by using DocumentFile. I can now create new directories and files. But still I am not sure about what's happening with File. Can anyone tell me what is happening?

I did the test on,

Device : Lenovo A2010-A

Android version : 5.1

Comment: Could you also post your final `newFile.path`? The whole exception stack is better

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 boolean created = newFile.mkdirs();
```

with

```
 boolean created = newFile.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `getCanonicalPath` and use `getAbsolutePath` instead. Below is how I create a new folder:

```
File newFile = new File(parent,dirName);
if(!newFile.exists()){
        boolean created = newFile.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace parent.getCanonicalPath() to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dirName);

if(!myDirectory.exists()) {

//create file if not generated                                 
myDirectory.mkdirs();

}else { 
//not created file
}
```